# What do you call a person working in law?

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

*Politics* is to *politician* as *law* is to what?

A hypernym for *lawyer/judge/law student*, etc.

**Edit:** Not only in the legal system, anyone practicing or researching the subject. Maybe politics wasn't the best example.

Comment: legal practitioner perhaps?

Comment: This may vary from country to country. In Britain the generic word is 'lawyer'. Alternatively 'a member of the legal profession'.

Comment: Can you analogise what you are looking for?

Comment: @coleopterist, I'm having a hard time finding one. Maybe trying to sum "law expert" into one word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*The Bar* usually refers to "lawyers or the legal profession" (see noun sense 14 in [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bar#Noun)) but I've occasionally seen it applied to the judiciary as well.  (The *[judiciary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/judiciary)* is "The court system and judges considered collectively, the judicial branch of government".)

Comment: Sense 14 rather than 13.

Comment: That will absolutely not work in England and Wales (and I think Scotland, though I'm not certain), where _the Bar_ (_barristers_) is one of two quite separate branches of the legal profession, the other being _solicitors_.

Comment: When you become a judge, you move from the Bar to the Bench.  I'd say *the legal profession* is closest; strictly speaking you aren't a *professional* until qualified, but it can be understood more loosely.

Comment: *The Bar* will not cover law students, paraplegals or researchers, and is usually used to refer to a particular level of court or jurisdiction.

Comment: @bib, *Paraplegals* is an interesting portmanteau!

Comment: If I could type, I would have had an honest job and not ended up as a lawyer

Answer (score 6):

I'd generally say **legal professionals**.

Answer (score 4):

Some of my law textbooks referred to such people as **Jurisprudents**:
— adj
1.  skilled in jurisprudence or versed in the principles of law

— n
2.  a jurisprudent person